# Java For Loop - Insert element after every n element

Tags: java, for-loop

I've had a look around but couldn't find anything applicable - this is in a vtl file, but it's the same syntax I think.

I want to insert something after every n elements, rather than replace the nth element of a for loop which I have done accidentally whilst trying to solve the problem. What would be the best way to approach this? There could be thousands of items to loop through.

My current code is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
  if(i % 5 == 0){
    //Show the nth element
  }
  else{
    //Display each table result normally
  }
}
```

Comment: do your loop reverse.. coz if you do from start you will end changing index of subsequent elements while adding new element, causing further inserts behave wrong.

Comment: data is an array or List? What is a vtl file?

Comment: Instead of putting the normal case behavior in an `else` block, make it unconditional, and put it before the `if`.  This assumes that you are performing output only, not modifying `data.results`.  Inasmuch as `data.results` appears to be an array, however, do be aware that Java arrays are fixed-length.  You cannot enlarge them.

Comment: It's a JSON File, @JohnBollinger I will try that now, but it sounds like it will work! Is there any way to mark a comment as an answer? It worked, can't believe I missed that haha

Comment: you need to use a list, I think you're using an array here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the else statement.
"else" means that the code will only be executed when the if-code is not executed.
But to insert something (with other words: execute both block) you need to execute the if-code and also execute the code that you always would.

Like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
  if(i % 5 == 0){
    //Show the nth element
  }
  //Display each table result normally
}
```

Comment: Actually the display should be before.

Comment: Are you sure? That would place the insert after the sixth element in the beginning. (0 to 4 are 5 elements!)

Comment: You are right but this would place something in the beginning and not at the end if there are say 10 elements.